# maven jaxb plugin, java packages generated has mis-match with XSD namespace

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

**Background**: I am trying to convert WSDL/XSD to Java classes

**Issue**: package names generated is mismatching with the namespace. Last part of number namespace is missing, below 02 is missing from package

XSD has - xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.**02**"

Java class generated - package iso.std.iso._20022.tech.xsd.pain_001_001;

**Steps Taken:**

I tried with 2 maven plugin, both gave me same results.

1. org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2
   maven-jaxb2-plugin
2. org.codehaus.mojo
   jaxb2-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me towards jaxb

Answer (score 0):

This works as designed. See Section D.5.2 of the [JAXB Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxb-2.2-mrel2a-oth-JSpec/).

Step 2 says:

> Remove the trailing file type, one of .?? or .??? or .html.

Apparently, `.02` is considered to be the "trailing file type" here and is removed.

Consider [using bindings to specify the target package](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configure-Target-Packages-in-Binding-Files).